# How to measure app downloads programmatically

Tags: android, google-play, apk

I have an Android application, that is packaged as a FAT binary( both ARM and x86 versions in one apk). I need to measure how many x86 devices installs happened vs ARM device install. Since this is a FAT binary,  there is only one version code, so play store only tells me the overall install. Is there a way to track it programatically or otherwise?

Answer (score 1):

First off, there might exist devices which support both ARM and x86.

You can use the active installs data from the Developer Console. It contains the number of active installs per device model. Using the device model you can determine the supported instruction sets. There might already exist databases for this mapping.

Additionally, you can retrieve the supported instruction sets programmatically using [Build.SUPPORTED_ABIS](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Build.html#SUPPORTED_ABIS) (or the now deprecated [Build.CPU_ABI](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Build.html#CPU_ABI) and [Build.CPU_ABI2](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Build.html#CPU_ABI2)).

Comment: Should i use Build.SUPPORTED_ABIs with the INSTALL_REFERER intent which will tell me when an app is installed? How do I get this value back on my developer console?

Comment: You'd have to take care of transmitting this information back to you/your server yourself. Probably some analytics solution could be used for this. Feel free to report the info at a suitable time, e.g., when your app is launched for the first time.